# MYSQL including a function in a string

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a trigger which returns the current date. But I'm struggling to include Curdate() function in a string

```
 DELIMITER $$ 
create trigger invalid_date 
    before insert on invoice 
    for each row 
begin 
    if new.date_in <> CURDATE() then 
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 
            "TriggerError: The date_in date should be Curdate()" ;
        end if ;
end$$ 
DELIMITER;
```

Doing it this way won't return the current date but rather just treat Curdate() as a string. My question is how do I include the Curdate() into the error message and actually return a date.

Comment: Have you tried CONCAT?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CONCAT function to print date.

```
message_text = CONCAT("Your string: ", CURDATE())
```